# I want only values of 1st index then 2nd and then 3rd index. How can I iterate through this with a loop and get the values dynamically?

Tags: php, arrays

I want the values from this array for each index. I tried to access the values using foreach but I can´t figure out how to get all values for each index (i.e. for 1st, 2nd, 3rd)

```
Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 244
                [1] => 6014
                [2] => 5067
                [3] => 5059
                [4] => 1726
                [5] => 56
                [6] => 1234
                [7] => 56
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 122
                [1] => 123
                [2] => 56
                [3] => 246
                [4] => 7360
                [5] => 8058
                [6] => 1290
                [7] => 1234
                [8] => 5454
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 7890
                [1] => 5454
            )

    )
```

Comment: `1st, 2nd, 3rd index` of *what*? The code/input shown (use a block quote *if* it is input rather than code (if code, you already "have" all of that `dynamically`?!)) looks "two-dimensional".

Answer (score 0):

Follow this sample I made, if you still don't get it, leave a comment.

```
$array = array(
        array('abc','def','xyz'),
        array('asd','fun','bad'),
        array('blue','red','green')


 );

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $subkey=>$subvalue) {
        echo $subkey . " : " . $subvalue . "<br>";
    }
}
```

If you want to get the currency pair key also, use this example:

```
$assoc_array = array(
        "eurusd" =>     array('abc','def','xyz'),
        "usdjpy" =>     array('good','bad','ugly'),
        "aususd" =>     array('blue','red','green')
```

);

```
foreach($assoc_array as $key=>$value){
        echo $key . ":: <br>";
    foreach($value as $subkey=>$subvalue) {
        echo $subkey . " : " . $subvalue . "<br>";
    }
}
```

[I want to show result this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5ruL.png)

Comment: See index 1, 2 and 3 are currency ids. I want to show each currency below their appropriate currency type(currency id). The 1st index has all the currencies of same currency type,2nd index has all the currency of same currency type. same for 3rd index

Comment: are you trying to use an associative array?  In other words, you want the index for each to have a name.

Answer (score 0):

*Please try this. hopefully It will help u.*

```
foreach ($array as $currencyId => $subArray){ 
    echo $currencyId . "<br>";

            foreach ($subArray as $value) {

                echo $value . "<br>";
            }
        }
```